# Flow-typing higher-order components for props injection (while preserving the optionality of defaultProps)

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, higher-order-components

**Background:**

1. Flow's documentation on typing higher-order components describes [props injection](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/hoc/#toc-injecting-props-with-a-higher-order-component) and the way of [supporting defaultProps](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/hoc/#toc-supporting-defaultprops-with-react-elementconfig), but the suggested code examples use different approaches, and there is no example of combining the two.
2. Since version 0.72, Flow has deprecated the inferred type `*` (asterisk).

**Problem**

I am trying to combine the recipes from Flow's documentation, and type a function that injects a certain property from the redux store into a supplied component. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component, type ComponentType, type ElementConfig } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import type { State } from 'client/types/redux';

export type InjectedProps = {
  xs: string[]
}

export default function injector<Props, Com: ComponentType<Props>>(
  DecoratedComponent: Com
) : ComponentType<$Diff<ElementConfig<Com>, InjectedProps>> {

  class Decorator extends Component<ElementConfig<Com>> {

    render() {
      return (
        <DecoratedComponent
          {...this.props} // the props will now contain xs from redux
        />
      );
    }

  }

  return connect((state: State)  => ({
    xs: state.xs
  }))(Decorator);
}
```

Here is a simplified version of this code (without redux) that gives the same error as the code above in [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiVnDAJ5hIFGRkUAqtS2NdcAogDZIQ5GIRIAzYAHM4AXzhioROAHIoqDMoDcAKG1d6ASRIArJBiQATAAqKwAZzgBeXNrhwAHnYBccOzCjAJJIA2gC62jK6SO6QsHAWSGIoAK588GLJJBjApHCBphjQADw2EPbYhCA+lUzCbHQltnYAfM0AFK5wACJm0CgwljWkwtVE2gCUcKPEzDD1SEUAJF3AYmJF-ILCohKSRZXN2EYFA9ZNrS6dnWowyVAk8pnZuQlofTDQbWBNPqX2kzhdG4AJBuN4kPweBzOYLKMQQCDKcJuFFwG53B4dVGooo9N5QfqDRjDCidbEonAAOmp3zKdki5NRnkcOE8DMZAHpmmSUeMdJ1IhEgA).

Notice that the [error disappears](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiVnDAJ5hIFGRkUAqtS2NdcAogDZIQ5GIRIAzYAHM4AXzhioROAHIoqDMoDcAKG1d6ASRIArJBiQATAAqKwAZzgBeXNrhwAHnYBccOzCjAJJIA2gC62jK6SO6QsHAWSGIoAK588GLJJBjApHCBphjQADw2EPbYhCA+lUzCbHRFAFQAfM0AFK5wACJm0CgwljWkwtVE2gCUcKPEzDD1SEUAJF3AYmJF-ILCohKSRZXN2EYFA9a2dq0unZ1qMMlQJPKZ2bkJaH0w0G1g5z6l9pMcLo3ABINzvEh+DwOZzBZRiCAQZThNyouC3e6PDpotFFHrvKD9QaMYYUTo41E4AB0NJ+ZTskQpaM8jhwnkZTIA9M1yajxjpOpEIkA) if the `*` type is used for the `ComponentType`.

Could you please suggest how to properly type this higher-order function without using the deprecated `*` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [fixed version](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiVnDAJ5hIFGRkUAqtS2NdcAogDZIQ5GIRIAzYAHM4AXzhioROAHIoqDMoDcAKG1d6ASRIArJBiQATAAqKwAZzgBeXNrhwAHnYBccOzCjAJJIA2gC62jK6SO6QsHAWSGIoAK588GLJJBjApHCBphjQADxGNhD2PniePn4BQWGy2IQgPs1Mwmx0JSRl9gB82ADyyTC93nAAJAAiwGJiRfyCwqISkkXNA3BGBTCWY319ABSucFNm0Ci7Fm2kwq1E2gCUcPfEzDCdSEXDo7Z2fS4Tic1DBklASPJMtlcgk0BcYNBDmA-j4fmNnjhdG4AJBuOEkPweBzOYLKMQQCDKcJuGlwEFgiHHWm0opnOFQS6WG7vE7Mmk4AB0QuR5TskT5tM8jhwnnFEoA9H1eTTHjoTpEIkA) of your simplified example.

```
import React, { Component, type ComponentType, type ElementConfig } from 'react';

type InjectedProps = {
  xs: string[]
}
// notice that InProps must contain an xs property that must be an array of strings
export default function injector<InProps: { xs: string[] }, Com: ComponentType<InProps>, OutProps: $Diff<ElementConfig<Com>, InjectedProps>>(
  DecoratedComponent: Com
) : ComponentType<OutProps> {

  return function decorator(props: OutProps) { // notice OutProps here
      const xs = ['foo']
      return (
        <DecoratedComponent
          {...props}
          xs={xs}
        />
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your fix translated nicely into my code for injecting fields from redux store into components. (At least I hope it did; I have not encountered errors yet.)